# Why ReplySubject has different behavior when subscribe to different observable with same sequence?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Example1 create the observable by Observable.Interval :

```
    var observable1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(3); 
    var replaySubject1 = new ReplaySubject<long>(); 
    observable1.Subscribe(replaySubject1); // subscribe 
    replaySubject1.Subscribe(onNext: x => Console.WriteLine($"first:{x}"));
    replaySubject1.Subscribe(onNext: x => Console.WriteLine($"second:{x}"));
    replaySubject1.Subscribe(onNext: x => Console.WriteLine($"third:{x}"));
```

The output as follow:

```
first:0
second:0
third:0
first:1
second:1
third:1
first:2
second:2
third:2
```

Example2 create the observable by Observable.Create :

```
        var observable2 = Observable.Create<long>(observer =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                observer.OnNext(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            observer.OnCompleted();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        }); 

        var replaySubject2 = new ReplaySubject<long>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        observable2.Subscribe(replaySubject2); // subscribe 
        replaySubject2.Subscribe(onNext: x => Console.WriteLine($"first:{x}"));
        replaySubject2.Subscribe(onNext: x => Console.WriteLine($"second:{x}"));
```

The output as follow:

```
first:0
first:1
first:2
second:0
second:1
second:2
third:0
third:1
third:2
```

The suppose that the examples would have the same output, however, I was wrong, Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the code in Observable.Create gets executed synchronously when you subscribe your ReplaySubject to the Observable.

Try this async version instead:

```
var observable2 = Observable.Create<long>(async observer =>
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        observer.OnNext(i);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    observer.OnCompleted();
    return Disposable.Empty;
});

var replaySubject2 = new ReplaySubject<long>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
observable2.Subscribe(replaySubject2); // subscribe 
replaySubject2.Subscribe(onNext: x => Console.WriteLine($"first:{x}"));
replaySubject2.Subscribe(onNext: x => Console.WriteLine($"second:{x}"));
replaySubject2.Subscribe(onNext: x => Console.WriteLine($"third:{x}"));
```

Alternatively have a look at SubscribeOn/ObserveOn.